# Django database migrations are gives no "No migrations to apply." error

Tags: python, django, django-migrations

Hi I am having issues trying to `migrate` my `django` database.
I have a database that definitely cant be cleared/removed, which is what most solutions recommend. However I do want the changes I made to my models to be applied to the database.
I have tried all the following command-sets:

```bash
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate --run-syncdb
```

```bash
python manage.py makemigrations django_project 
python manage.py migrate django_project
python manage.py migrate
```

```bash
python manage.py makemigrations && python manage.py migrate
```

```bash
python manage.py makemigrations django_project
python manage.py migrate --fake-initial
python manage.py migrate
```

I cleared the migrations folder everytime.
Every set resulted in the same response:

```bash
08:59 ~/GluoApi $ python manage.py makemigrations && python manage.py migrate
Migrations for 'django_project':
  django_project/migrations/0001_initial.py
    - Create model Blacklist
    - Create model Like
    - Create model Post
    - Create model PostReaction
    - Create model Profile
    - Create model Token
    - Create model ReportUser
    - Create model ReportPost
    - Add field reports to profile
    - Add field requests to profile
    - Add field user to profile
    - Create model PostReactionReport
    - Create model PostReactionLike
    - Add field likes to postreaction
    - Add field post to postreaction
    - Add field poster to postreaction
    - Add field reports to postreaction
    - Add field likes to post
    - Add field poster to post
    - Add field reports to post
    - Add field post to like
    - Add field user to like
    - Create model GiftLink
    - Create model AuthToken
    - Create model Article
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: admin, auth, authtoken, contenttypes, django_project, sessions, sites
Running migrations:
  No migrations to apply.
  Your models in app(s): 'django_project' have changes that are not yet reflected in a migration, and so won't be applied.
  Run 'manage.py makemigrations' to make new migrations, and then re-run 'manage.py migrate' to apply them.
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you cleared the **django_migrations** table in your database too ?

This table contains probably a tuple ('django_project', '0001_initial') which tell to Django that the initial migration has been already applied, so the `migrate` command tell you there is not migrations to apply.

But you tell, you can't remove the database, so if you just want to apply migration without make the operations, you can call: `makemigrations && migrate --fake`, for applying the migrations without really change the database

Comment: Will Deleting the **djang_migrations** table affect the rest of my database?

Comment: No, but, when you recall the migrate, django will try to reapply migration and so, if some operation can't be executed, you will have an error in the console. So if you remove an entry in django_migration, you have to delete the corresponding mgiration operation in your database or call `migrate --fake` for applying migrations without change the database schema

Comment: Wait I might have been unclear about something. I dont want any dataloss, but I do want the changes I made to my models to get applied on the database.

Comment: Have you check, as i said, if you table django_migration already contains a 0001_initial migration ? I explained why your app think there is no migration to apply. you do not answer about this question. i cannot help more you